# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for List<T>.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my method I have multiple statements that are filtering data and returning and object. Because I want to serve the view with an view model I instantiate a list and then pass it into view...

Simplified example.

```
    List<viewModel> returnedViewModel = new List<viewModel>();

    foreach (var item in filteredData)
    {
        returnedViewModel.Add( // this line is throwing error
        new viewModel
        {
            data = item,
        });
    }
```

The issue is that I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for returnedViewModel.Add for one particular filteredData object while other are not causing that issue.

I'm after a possible source of that problem not the solution.

I'm using EF and have a MARS statement in my connectionString. Can that be an issue?

Whole statment:

```
public ActionResult RenderPartialSearchableEventStacks(string viewType,
                                                       string orderColumn,
                                                       string sortOrder,
                                                       int? stackNumber,
                                                       string adminName,
                                                       string clientName,
                                                       string stackType,
                                                       string stackStatus,
                                                       int? adminId = null)
{
    IEnumerable<blsEventStack> eventStacks = unitOfWork.EventStackRepository.Filter(n => (stackNumber == null) || n.EventStackId == stackNumber,
                                                                                    n => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(adminName)) || n.ManagingAdminName.Contains(adminName),
                                                                                    n => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(clientName)) || n.RelatedClientName.Contains(clientName),
                                                                                    n => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stackType)) || n.EventStackType.Contains(stackType),
                                                                                    n => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stackStatus)) || n.EventStackLastEventStatus.Contains(stackStatus));

    IEnumerable<blsEventStack> viewTypeRelatedEventStacks = eventStacks;

    if (viewType == "allEventStacks")
    {
        viewTypeRelatedEventStacks = unitOfWork.EventStackRepository.GetAll();
    }

    if (viewType == "assignedEventStacks")
    {
        // Needed to filter out results with empty (unassigned) admin name
        viewTypeRelatedEventStacks = from x in eventStacks
                                     where x.ManagingAdminName != null
                                     select x;
    }

    if (viewType == "singleAdminAssignedEventStacks")
    {
        string singleAdminName;

        if (adminId != null)
        {
            // Gets admin name using adminId
            singleAdminName = unitOfWork.AdminRepository.GetById(adminId).AdminName;
        }
        else
        {
            MembershipUser admin = Membership.GetUser();

            blsAdmin loggedInAdmin = (from x in unitOfWork.AdminRepository.GetAll()
                                      where x.AdminEmail == admin.Email
                                      select x).FirstOrDefault();

            singleAdminName = loggedInAdmin.AdminName;

            ViewBag.adminView = true;
        }

        // Gets all eventStacks that belong to a give adminName
        viewTypeRelatedEventStacks = from x in eventStacks
                                     where x.ManagingAdminName == singleAdminName
                                     select x;

        ViewBag.adminId = adminId;
    }

    IEnumerable<blsEventStack> returnedEventStacks = viewTypeRelatedEventStacks;

    if (orderColumn == "stack")
    {
        if (sortOrder == "descendingStack")
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackId descending
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = null;
        }
        else
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = "descendingStack";
        }
    }

    if (orderColumn == "managingAdmin")
    {
        if (sortOrder == "descendingManagingAdmin")
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.ManagingAdminName descending
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = null;
        }
        else
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.ManagingAdminName
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = "descendingManagingAdmin";
        }
    }

    if (orderColumn == "relatedClient")
    {
        if (sortOrder == "descendingRelatedClient")
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.RelatedClientName descending
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = null;
        }
        else
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.RelatedClientName
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = "descendingRelatedClient";
        }
    }

    if (orderColumn == "stackType")
    {
        if (sortOrder == "descendingStackType")
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackType descending
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = null;
        }
        else
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackType
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = "descendingStackType";
        }
    }

    if (orderColumn == "latestEventTime")
    {
        if (sortOrder == "descendingLatestEventTime")
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackLastEventTime descending
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = null;
        }
        else
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackLastEventTime
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = "descendingLatestEventTime";
        }
    }

    if (orderColumn == "latestEventStatus")
    {
        if (sortOrder == "descendingLatestEventStatus")
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackLastEventStatus descending
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = null;
        }
        else
        {
            returnedEventStacks = from x in viewTypeRelatedEventStacks
                                  orderby x.EventStackLastEventStatus
                                  select x;
            sortOrder = "descendingLatestEventStatus";
        }
    }

    List<ViewModelAllEventStacks> returnedViewModel = new List<ViewModelAllEventStacks>();

    foreach (var item in returnedEventStacks)
    {
        returnedViewModel.Add( 
        new ViewModelAllEventStacks
        {
            EventStack = item,
            AdminId = item.AdminEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().AdminId,
            ClientId = item.ClientEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().ClientId
        });
    }

    ViewBag.stackNumber = stackNumber;
    ViewBag.adminName = adminName;
    ViewBag.clientName = clientName;
    ViewBag.stackType = stackType;
    ViewBag.stackStatus = stackStatus;

    // ViewBag passing state of existing order
    ViewBag.sortOrder = sortOrder;

    // ViewBag passing view data (ex. assignedEventStacks, allEventStacks, etc.)
    ViewBag.viewType = viewType;

    return PartialView("BLS_AllEventStacks", returnedViewModel);
}
```

Comment: At runtime, *which* object is actually `null`?

Comment: You should try & cast it, and see if 'item' is initialized.
And what is "data"? We're seeing only a tiny bit of the puzzle.

Comment: Is the `viewModel` (urgh - please use conventional type names) constructor throwing the exception? Maybe the assignment to the `data` property/field? Separate out the construction of the `viewModel` from the addition to the list...

Comment: Could you be dereferencing something null in your `filteredData` query?

Comment: You said `Simplified example`, is there any other code between `List<viewModel> returnedViewModel = new List<viewModel>();` and the `foreach` block?

Comment: Is the `data` method of your model an auto property or something more complex? We need more context to understand the problem.

Comment: @ekad there is no additional code. All that is "simplified" is that I didn't add all the properties that are being populated in the new viewModel object.

Comment: did you test your connection beforehand and get 'succeeded', and also it sounds like there is no data being retrieved - pretty much ensure your viewmodel has data

Comment: Could you add that code? Also the constructor for viewModel and any properties that aren't automatic.

Comment: @Jon Skeet that "viewModel" identifier is used only in that simplified example (sorry for that misappropriate naming).

Comment: There is only a way to find out. Start to use a DEBUGGER.

Comment: @ChrisHermut if there's more properties beside `data = item` inside `new viewModel { ... }`, then please add them all, the error might be from the other properties.

Comment: @ChrisHermut: It's entirely possible that one of the properties you've missed out is the problem, e.g. `ZipCode = person.Address.ZipCode` will fail if `person.Address` is null. The problem is almost certainly *not* in the code you've shown us.

Comment: If you're new to mvc, i'd have a look at this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-webgrid-in-mvc-4-using-simple-model-and-data/ - Helped me out a lot with getting ideas straight!!

Comment: I've added the whole method block hope that it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your time and not killing me with downvotes. Another lesson well learned. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 possible reasons:

1. Your code in debug isn't what's actually running and is stale.
2. There is a null exception in the `viewModel` constructor.
3. There is a null exception happening in the `data` property.
4. As noted in the comments, there is some code you filtered out that was actually setting the list to `null`.

Based on edited question

```
returnedViewModel.Add( 
    new ViewModelAllEventStacks
    {
        EventStack = item,
        AdminId = item.AdminEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().AdminId,
        ClientId = item.ClientEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().ClientId
    });
```

if there are no `AdminEventLogs` or `ClientEventLogs` this will throw the null exception error. Also possible but unlikely, `item` is null.

Comment: Yes those two last lines where the problem (of course). The actual issue is the error in logic (those properties shouldn't be null). Thanks for reminding me why I always have to check if an actual object exists before calling it's properties.

Comment: Dereferencing a object returned by `FirstOrDefault` without checking for `null` always a problem (if `T` is of reference type). You need to check for null before accessing it..

Answer (score 1):

I believe these two lines are the problem. When you use `item.AdminEventLogs.FirstOrDefault()`, it will be null if `item.AdminEventLogs` doesn't have any elements, so accessing `.AdminId` will raise an error. The same thing also applies to `item.ClientEventLogs.FirstOrDefault()`

```
AdminId = item.AdminEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().AdminId,
ClientId = item.ClientEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().ClientId
```

You can use `.Any()` to check whether `item.AdminEventLogs` and `item.ClientEventLogs` have any elements. If so, use the `AdminId` and `ClientId` of the first element, otherwise set `AdminId` and `ClientId` to 0 (assuming `AdminId` and `ClientId` are integers)

```
AdminId = item.AdminEventLogs.Any() ? item.AdminEventLogs.First().AdminId : 0,
ClientId = item.ClientEventLogs.Any() ? item.ClientEventLogs.First().ClientId : 0
```

Comment: Thanks. To be honest never used .any() extension method. I wasn't using ternary operator for that because the always have to be a valid admin/clientId. The issue was that scenario was added where the was no adminEventLog created so it was passing null for item.AdminEventLogs.FirstOrDefault().AdminId.